# Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND css html5

Tags: html, css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="format1.css">
  <title>My Favorite Movie</title>
</head>
<body>
```

This is my code but when I check the dev tools, it shows the error message on the title. The .html and the .css are in the same folder. Any help is appreciated!

I have tried making a separate css file and tried linking that but still no luck.

Comment: _"I have tried making a separate css file and tried linking that"_... isn't that what's in your question? There's a very simple cause for this error, the file by the name `format1.css` does not exist. What makes you think it does?

Comment: can you show the folder structure and how do you run the code

Comment: @Liap. I had them all in 1 folder, but tried moving the .css files to its own separate folder.
<link rel="stylesheet" href="C:\CITC 1300 Beginning HTML\MyChapter3\css\format2.css">

Comment: @Glum_Excitement the info you provide is `format2.css` not `format1.css`

 try `<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/format2.css">`

Comment: @Liap Yes. I have one html with format1.css and another with format 2.css. Neither one is being detected.

Answer (score -2):

check your format1.css folder path.

Comment: Hi Hiskia! Thanks for the reply. I right clicked my format1.css and copied the path, pasted the path into the html code and still cant get it to work.

<link rel="stylesheet" href="C:\CITC 1300 Beginning HTML\MyChapter3\format2.css">

Comment: this is not a answer it is just a comment